# Nginx redirect from subfolder to a folder of that subfolder

Tags: nginx

I'm adding languages to my wordpress blog. Until now, I had it under:
https://mywebsite.com/blog/

I'm using a wordpress extension https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/. All management is done under https://mywebsite.com/blog/, but frontend languages are under:

```
https://mywebsite.com/blog/es
https://mywebsite.com/blog/en
https://mywebsite.com/blog/fr
```

I would like to redirect all articles from my original blog in Spanish (which actually end by .html) to /blog/es/. For example:

```
https://mywebsite.com/blog/article1.html » https://mywebsite.com/blog/es/article1.html
```

Keeping in mind that this will only apply this type of urls. We could use .html as a filter.

I've tried different approaches. But they don't work...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what did you try?

Something like this should work:

```
location ~ ^/blog/([^/]+\.html)$ {
    return 301 $scheme://mywebsite.com/blog/es/$1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did not work correctly, but lent me to the correct configuration (I'll answer with the correct answer). The problem with this option is that I ended up with /es/es/es/es/es...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @slauth comment, I ended up with the correct syntax:

```
location ~ ^/blog/(.*)\.html {
    return 301 $scheme://mywebsite.com/blog/es/$1;
}
```

For other people that are having trouble with this type of redirections, try always to isolate the redirection (remove other redirections that you're testing, in case there's a conflict).

Comment: This is missing the final `.html`, i.e. `/blog/foo.html` will be redirected to `/blog/es/foo`…